# getting a combination of column values in TSQL

Tags: t-sql

I have a database structure like this

```
rowid   deltaValue  Applicable
1        r            n/d
1        w            n/d
1        m            n/d
2        r            n/d
2        w            n/d
2        m            n/d
3        r            n/d
3        w            n/r
3        m            n/d
```

so basically I want to only select the last group of 'rowid', ie `rowid=3`. This is because it is the only group that has a combination of `n/d, n/r`

is there a tsql query that will just look at the combination and pull the group (ie, the rowid). 
Here is what I have so far:

```
select  *
from table
where 1=1
and deltaValue in ('r','w','m')
and ((   1=(case when [DeltaValue] = 'r' and [Applicable]='n/r' then 1 else 0 end)
     and 1=(case when [DeltaValue] = 'w' and [Applicable]='n/d' then 1 else 0 end)
     and 1=(case when [DeltaValue] = 'm' and [Applicable]='n/d' then 1 else 0 end)
     ) OR
     (   1=(case when [DeltaValue] = 'r' and [Applicable]='n/d' then 1 else 0 end)
     and 1=(case when [DeltaValue] = 'w' and [Applicable]='n/r' then 1 else 0 end)
     and 1=(case when [DeltaValue] = 'm' and [Applicable]='n/d' then 1 else 0 end)
     ) OR
     (   1=(case when [DeltaValue] = 'r' and [Applicable]='n/d' then 1 else 0 end)
     and 1=(case when [DeltaValue] = 'w' and [Applicable]='n/d' then 1 else 0 end)
     and 1=(case when [DeltaValue] = 'm' and [Applicable]='n/r' then 1 else 0 end)
     )
    )
```

Output:

```
3        r            n/d
3        w            n/r
3        m            n/d
```

Comment: Can you show us your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
with temp as
(
    SELECT t.rowid
    FROM myTable t
    GROUP BY t.rowid
    HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Applicable= 'n/d' THEN 1 END) > 0
       AND COUNT(CASE WHEN Applicable= 'n/r' THEN 1 END) > 0;
)
select * from MyTable as mt
INNER JOIN temp as t
ON mt.RowId = t.RowId
```

Comment: rowid= 'n/d'   <---this does not make sense

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this one

```
SELECT      *
FROM        Table1
WHERE       rowid IN ( SELECT rowid
                       FROM   ( SELECT * , DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY rowid ORDER     BY Applicable) AS myRank FROM Table1
                              ) AS t
                       WHERE  t.myRank > 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

The following could be considered a development on [@Abe Miessler's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12145529/297408) suggestion:

```
WITH counted AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    [n/d count] = COUNT(CASE DeltaValue WHEN 'n/d' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY rowid),
    [n/r count] = COUNT(CASE DeltaValue WHEN 'n/r' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY rowid)
  FROM atable
)
SELECT
  rowid,
  DeltaValue,
  Applicable
FROM counted
WHERE [n/d count] > 0 AND [n/r count] > 0
;
```

As you can see, you can avoid the join by using a [*windowing*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) version of the `COUNT()` aggregate function.

By the way, if you ever need to make the query more universal and such that returns any group that has more than one distinct `DeltaValue`, you could use a slightly different approach:

```
WITH counted AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    MinDeltaValue = MIN(DeltaValue) OVER (PARTITION BY rowid),
    MaxDeltaValue = MAX(DeltaValue) OVER (PARTITION BY rowid)
  FROM atable
)
SELECT
  rowid,
  DeltaValue,
  Applicable
FROM counted
WHERE MinDeltaValue <> MaxDeltaValue
;
```

The above query uses windowing `MAX()` and `MIN()` to find the minimum and maximum values per group (of `rowid`) and returns those groups where the minimum is different from the maximum.